# How to test objects of formal generic types for equality in Eiffel?

Tags: eiffel, eiffel-studio-18

I should test for equality two generic attributes like

```
a, b: G
...
Result := a.is_equal (b)
```

but VUTA (target rule validity) says "*separate target of the Object_call is not controlled*". What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are different options to fix this issue that rely only on changes in your code:

1. Add a non-separate constraint for the formal generic parameter. By default, the constraint is `detachable separate ANY`. E.g., if you have the declaration

   ```
   class FOO [G] ...
   ```

   then specifing explicit constraint `ANY` (without `separate`) should do the trick:

   ```
   class FOO [G -> ANY] ...
   ```

   With this change, all instances of type G also become attached. If this should be avoided, the constraint `ANY` should be replaced with `detachable ANY`, but the code should be updated to check that the attributes are attached before use:

   ```
   Result := attached a as x and then attached b as y and then x.is_equal (y)
   ```
2. Wrap the target of the call to make it controlled. Here is the example with a separate instruction (similar code could be written using a dedicated feature, e.g. if you have many such equality tests):

   ```
   separate a as x do
       Result := attached x and then attached b as y and then x.is_equal (b)
   end
   ```

It's also possible to change your project settings to avoid using SCOOP if it is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

it seems when you go to doctor...

```
Result := attached a as x and then attached b as y and then y.is_equal (x)
```

... alexander thank you for the editing

Comment: This is an asnwer to another error, not about `separate` status of objects, but about their attachment status.